# Congruent Modulo with negative

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $16 \equiv 7 \pmod m$.

Find $m$:

$$7-16 = -9$$

so, the $m$ can be what ever can divide into $-9$ ?

Comment: The answer is yes **if** you meant that m can be anything that *divides* m...

Comment: There is not only one solution.

Comment: So If I have the following options a] m = mod 2, b] m = mod 5, c] m = mod 7, d] m = mod 10, e] mod 3 :: the answer is mod 3? [e]?

Comment: Yes @MethodManX...but again: what's your definition of "equality modulo m"?

Comment: = means congruency

Comment: *sigh*...ok, @MethodManX: so how do **you** define "a congruent to b modulo m", or $\,a=b\pmod m\,$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$16=7\pmod m\iff  16-7=9=0\pmod m\iff m\mid 9\implies m=\ldots$$

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying @ DonAntonio

Comment: What's the definition of $\,a=b\pmod m\,$ you know, @MethodManX ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that: $$16 \equiv 7 \mod m$$ means $$16=7+km,\text{ for some } k\in \mathbb Z$$ And if we put $r=-k$ we can formulate the alternative $$7=16-km=16+rm\text{ with }r\in\mathbb Z$$

So we have either $9=km,$ or $-9=-km=rm$. The two formulations are entirely equivalent. $m$ is taken as being positive.